# how to locate an image using base directory in graphic location in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to locate my base directory folder in debug folder for my graphic location but I don't know what query should I put. Can someone help me with this?

I've tried using the folder location which is "'C:\project\debug\qrfolder\' & {TableName_StoredProc;1.ColumnName}"  but when I tried to open my project on another pc the picture doesn't change...

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly save or copy the image to a folder that exists on both machines (for example, the temp folder). Then, use that path in the graphic location expression within Crystal.